# Testing conditions on a function's parameter using testthat

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I have a function of the form `func(expr, data.sizes)`, where the parameter `expr` is an expression and the one named `data.sizes` is ordinarily as the name suggests, a vector or sequence of data sizes. (eg: `c(10, 100, 1000)` or `10^seq(1, 3)`)

I would like to write some test-cases for my function's parameters using `testthat`, but am new to unit-testing in R so I would like to know how does one test conditions for a function's parameter(s) using `testthat`?

For instance, I want to check for a possible NA value for the parameter `data.size` in my function and I wrote this snippet to test in my console: (function is available in Global Env.)

```r
test_that("NA test for data.sizes", {
  expect_false(is.na(data.sizes %in% func(expression, data.sizes = c(10, 100))))
})
```

which throws the error:

```
* object 'data.sizes' not found
1: expect_false(is.na(data.sizes %in% func(expression, data.sizes = c(10, 
       10)))) at :2
2: quasi_label(enquo(object), label, arg = "object")
3: eval_bare(get_expr(quo), get_env(quo))
4: data.sizes %in% func(expression, data.sizes = c(10, 10))
```

What might I be possibly doing wrong? Also what would be the syntax in general to apply test conditions on a function's parameters using testthat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

testthat checks if the result of the function is what you expect.

If you want to test the result of the function to NAs, you can make a specific test for this :

```
library(testthat)
library(assertthat)

func <- function(expr,data.sizes) {
  assert_that(noNA(data.sizes))
  eval(expr)
}

test_that("data.sizes test for func", {
  # Success
  expect_error(func(expression(data.sizes[1]+data.sizes[2]), data.sizes = c(1,NA)))
  expect_equal(func(expression(data.sizes[1]+data.sizes[2]), data.sizes = c(1,2)),3)
  # Failure
  expect_equal(func(expression(data.sizes[1]+data.sizes[2]), data.sizes = c(1,2)),4)
})
```

To test validity of parameters inside the function, you can use [assertive programming](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkr/vignettes/assertive-programming.html) packages like assertthat.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test can test the output of your function with a given input. It is *not* a way of allowing your function to screen the given variables for inappropriate inputs. This has to be done inside your function.

The unit test must simply call your function with some parameters and ensure the output is what is expected.

Suppose for example that you want `func` to return a list containing repetitions of the evaluated expression according to `data.sizes`, like this:

```
func <- function(expression, data.sizes)
{
  expression <- as.expression(as.list(match.call())$expression)
  if(!all(!is.na(data.sizes))) stop("data.sizes may not contain NAs")
  lapply(data.sizes, function(x) rep(eval(expression), x))
}
```

So that it does something like this:

```
y <- 5
func(y^2 + 3, 1:3)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 28
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 28 28
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 28 28 28
```

But you want an exception to be thrown if there are `NA` values in `data.sizes`:

```
func(y^2 + 3, c(1, NA))
#> Error in func(y^2 + 3, c(1, NA)) : data.sizes may not contain NAs
```

Then your unit test would look like this:

```
test_that("NA test for data.sizes", {
  expect_list(func(y^2 + 3, 1:3))
  expect_error(func(y^2 + 3, c(1, NA)))
})
```

So you know if this test passes, your error is being picked up appropriately

Comment: This makes it clear. So we provide corner cases (eg: null/NA/NaN checks with corresponding `stop()` calls) inside our function, and `testthat` only checks for specific input cases provided we handle those in our function pre-emptively, and not for a generalized test-case scenario. Thanks for a detailed example as well! Upvoted, wish I could accept multiple answers.

Comment: @Anirban166 exactly. These tests become necessary when you are building a new package. When your code base becomes large and has multiple functions that rely on other functions within your package, then a change to one function can have unexpected effects elsewhere. Automated tests allow you to make sure everything still works as expected after a change.